# how can i install gym[box2d] despite errors below?

Tags: python, pip, box2d, openai-gym

when i try to install gym[box2d] i get following error:
i tried: pip install gym[box2d].
on anaconda prompt i installed swig and gym[box2d] but i code in python3.9 env and it still not working.(my text editor is pycharm)
gym is already installed.and

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\hooman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\hoom
an\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_vo0km5i\\box2d-py_aea38b0da25341cf93e6a6c9d4b9d296\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\hooman\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pi
p-install-_vo0km5i\\box2d-py_aea38b0da25341cf93e6a6c9d4b9d296\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else
 io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exe
c'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\hooman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-va_dgazk'
       cwd: C:\Users\hooman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_vo0km5i\box2d-py_aea38b0da25341cf93e6a6c9d4b9d296\
  Complete output (16 lines):
  Using setuptools (version 58.2.0).
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Box2D
  copying library\Box2D\Box2D.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Box2D
  copying library\Box2D\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Box2D
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Box2D\b2
  copying library\Box2D\b2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Box2D\b2
  running build_ext
  building 'Box2D._Box2D' extension
  swigging Box2D\Box2D.i to Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp
  swig.exe -python -c++ -IBox2D -small -O -includeall -ignoremissing -w201 -globals b2Globals -outdir library\Box2D -keyword -w511 -D_SWIG_KWARGS -o Box2D\Box2D_wr
ap.cpp Box2D\Box2D.i
  error: command 'swig.exe' failed: None
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for box2d-py
  Running setup.py clean for box2d-py
Failed to build box2d-py
Installing collected packages: box2d-py
    Running setup.py install for box2d-py ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\hooman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ho
oman\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_vo0km5i\\box2d-py_aea38b0da25341cf93e6a6c9d4b9d296\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\hooman\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\
pip-install-_vo0km5i\\box2d-py_aea38b0da25341cf93e6a6c9d4b9d296\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) el
se io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'e
xec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\hooman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-yz4t1mq0\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-he
aders 'C:\Users\hooman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Include\box2d-py'
         cwd: C:\Users\hooman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_vo0km5i\box2d-py_aea38b0da25341cf93e6a6c9d4b9d296\
    Complete output (16 lines):
    Using setuptools (version 58.2.0).
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Box2D
    copying library\Box2D\Box2D.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Box2D
    copying library\Box2D\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Box2D
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Box2D\b2
    copying library\Box2D\b2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Box2D\b2
    running build_ext
    building 'Box2D._Box2D' extension
    swigging Box2D\Box2D.i to Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp
    swig.exe -python -c++ -IBox2D -small -O -includeall -ignoremissing -w201 -globals b2Globals -outdir library\Box2D -keyword -w511 -D_SWIG_KWARGS -o Box2D\Box2D_
wrap.cpp Box2D\Box2D.i
    error: command 'swig.exe' failed: None
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

according to [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gym-box2d), you should use the following command

```
conda install -c conda-forge gym-box2d
```

but you can still just install **gym** and `from gym.envs import box2d`

Comment: on anaconda prompt it installs but i code in python env and error is still there in pycharm.

Comment: then please try the import thing `from gym.envs import box2d`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using windows for using openai gym which is not officially supported. gym installation for windows is not stable. Linux and mac are officially supported. I recommended this video [Installing OpenAI Gym (gym[all]) on Linux, Windows and Mac](https://youtu.be/e3DyCg0fgx0) for installing in Linux. you can use wsl2 in windows which i tried and worked.

Also this doc [gym 0.7.4](https://pypi.org/project/gym/0.7.4/) helped me to set up the display in using wsl2(alias linux server according to the docs ).

Individual installation like box2d did not work for me. Try to install all gym envs as said in the video(takes a lot of space  but no other option)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may go to [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) and find `pybox2d` and download the version which match your python version and run `pip install Box2D‑2.3.10‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl` (change your wheel name!)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to download and install the latest stable version of **Build Tools pour Visual Studio** (2022 currently) and to select **C++ package** during the installation. Then the `pip install gym[box2d]` worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Mac Pro 2016 and I had to first install Anaconda. It took a while to finish installation, so make sure you have some time to keep your PC running until this command is done.

> brew install --cask anaconda

Setup the environment path.

> brew install zsh

Restart terminal, then:

> export PATH="/usr/local/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
> source /Users/my_username/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate

After, install the package

> conda install -c conda-forge gym-box2d